# What is meant by setting up a bare-bones server in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have to setup a bare-bones server. What is meant by bare-bones? I am assuming this means I can't use `ExpressJS` which I normally do with NodeJS. Am I correct with my assumption or is there more to this that I am missing?

Comment: That question is vague and depends on the asker's intentions. In general, yes. I would assume that means setting up a node server with no outside frameworks such as Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `HTTP` library.

The `HTTP` library is what express is built on, and is one of the most bare-bones ways you can create a server.
However, it is primarily up to who asked you to do it, so you should clarify with them first.